# My share button is not working to share the images in View Pager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android. I am trying to fix share button to share the View Pager images.This is my code.  Here I added one button in ViewPager xml page to share the content. And I added the onclick event to share that particular image. But it is not working.

```
public class quotes extends AppCompatActivity {

private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
Button btn;
ViewPager viewPager=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quotes_pager);
    btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.share);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter(this));

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("image/jpg");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
            int position=viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is my share button

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<Button
    android:text="share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/share" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my page item Image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to explore setDataAndType(Uri data, String type) and use that instead of setType..

Comment: Thanks Patel, It is working now.  But it is showing share option only sms. How to add another share options?